# How can we load AspxTreelist in Dev Express from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

How can we load ASPxTreelist in Dev Express  from database. I am using DataTable to retrieve the data from database.
visual studio 2010 + csharp.net
Im using ASPxTreeList control, I want to add Nodes and sub Nodes programmatically,

Answer (score 1):

it is very easy:

[Connecting the ASPxTreeList to a Data Source](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3957)

as you can see in that page, once you have your DataTable assign it as DataSource, set couple of other fields then call `DataBind` method.

if you need to customize columns etc you can either do it from code or use the Designer.

check this one as well of course: [Tree Generation Algorithm](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3977)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "[How to: Bind the ASPxTreeList to Data Created at Runtime](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4015)" sample that illustrates how to accomplish this task with the use of the DataTable at runtime.